# My perl script isn't working, I have a feeling it's the grep command

Tags: perl, grep

I'm trying for search in the one file for instances of the
number and post if the other file contains those numbers

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(file, "textIds.txt"); #
        @file = <file>;         #file looking into
#        close file;            #
while(<>){
        $temp = $_;
        $temp =~ tr/|/\t/;      #puts tab between name and id
        @arrayTemp = split("\t", $temp);
        @found=grep{/$arrayTemp[1]/} <file>;
        if (defined $found[0]){
        #if (grep{/$arrayTemp[1]/} <file>){
                print $_;
        }
        @found=();
}
print "\n";
close file;

#the input file lines have the format of 
#John|7791  154
#Smith|5432 290
#Conor|6590 897

#And in the file the format is 
#5432
#7791
#6590
#23140
```

Comment: Print out `$arrayTemp[1]` and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: you've slurped in the entire file contents into `@file` in the third line of your script, but then you're attempting to read more lines from it again in your grep statement.  At that point, `<file>` has no further contents to return to you, and it's just returning `undef` every time.  If you'd enable `use warnings;` in your code, Perl would have told you that.

Comment: @PaulL Your point to use `warnings` (and `strict`, even though you didn't say it) is well-taken, but this code wouldn't actually produce any warnings. We don't know what the command line arguments are in this case, so it's hard to say what the null filehandle would do. But even a `while (<file>)` would do nothing; the code simply wouldn't enter the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl script grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082184/perl-script-grep)

Comment: @MattJacob you are absolutely correct.  My apologies.  I was screwing up context - I wasn't taking into account that `grep` forced a list context on the `<>` operator.  If it had worked in scalar context, *then* it would have returned `undef`, which Perl would certainly warn about using.  As it is, though, (and assuming the four lines with just numbers are the contents of `textIDs.txt` and the other file is passed on the command line), the `<file>` will simply return an empty list, which grep is perfectly happy to use without warnings.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues in your script.

1. ***Always*** include `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.
   This would have told you about odd things in your script in advance.
2. Never use barewords as filehandles as they are global identifiers. Use three-parameter-open
   instead: `open( my $fh, '<', 'testIds.txt');`
3. `use autodie;` or check whether the opening worked.
4. You read and store `testIds.txt` into the array `@file` but later on (in your `grep`) you are
   again trying to read from that file(handle) (with `<file>`). As @PaulL said, this will always
   give `undef` (false) because the file was already read.
5. Replacing `|` with tabs and then splitting at tabs is not neccessary. You can split at the 
   tabs and pipes at the same time as well (assuming "John|7791  154" is *really* "John|7791\t154").
6. Your talking about "input file" and "in file" without exactly telling which is which.
   I assume your "textIds.txt" is the one with only the numbers and the other *input file* is the
   one read from STDIN (with the `|`'s in it).

With this in mind your script could be written as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Open 'textIds.txt' and slurp it into the array @file:
open( my $fh, '<', 'textIds.txt') or die "cannot open file: $!\n";
my @file = <$fh>;
close($fh);

# iterate over STDIN and compare with lines from 'textIds.txt':
while( my $line = <>) {
    # split "John|7791\t154" into ("John", "7791", "154"):
    my ($name, $number1, $number2) = split(/\||\t/, $line);

    # compare $number1 to each member of @file and print if found:
    if ( grep( /$number1/, @file) ) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```