# Perl script grep

Tags: perl, grep

The script is printing the amount of input lines, I want it to print the amount of input lines that are present in another file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open("file", "text.txt"); 
        @todd = <file>;         
        close "file";
while(<>){
        if( grep( /^$_$/, @todd)){
        #if( grep @todd, /^$_$/){
                print $_;
        }
        print "\n";
}
```

if for example file contains

```
1
3
4
5
7
```

and the input file that will be read from contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I would want it to print 1,3,4,5 and 7
but 1-9 are being printed instead

UPDATE******
This is my code now and I am getting this error
readline() on closed filehandle todd at ./may6test.pl line 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open("todd", "<text.txt");
        @files = <todd>;         #file looking into
        close "todd";
while( my $line = <> ){
        chomp $line;
        if ( grep( /^$line$/, @files) ) {
                print $_;
        }
        print "\n";
}
```

which makes no sense to me because I have this other script that is basically doing the same thing

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open("file", "<text2.txt");    #
        @file = <file>;         #file looking into
        close "file";           #
while(<>){
        $temp = $_;
        $temp =~ tr/|/\t/;      #puts tab between name and id
        my ($name, $number1, $number2) = split("\t", $temp);
        if ( grep( /^$number1$/, @file) ) {
                print $_;
        }
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: This is almost the same Q as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37079760/5830574) posed 3hrs ago. If you are the same person I strongly recommend ***not to double post*** from different accounts. Else I recommend to look out for the very same questions already posted on SO.

Comment: Rule of thumb: avoid using `$_` implicitly or explicitly for exactly this reason. `map` and `grep` are exceptions because its use is required.

Answer (score 5):

OK, the problem here is - `grep` sets `$_` too. So `grep { $_ } @array` will always give you every element in the array.

At a basic level - you need to:

```
while ( my $line = <> ) { 
   chomp $line; 
   if ( grep { /^$line$/ } @todd ) { 
      #do something
   }
}
```

But I'd suggest instead that you might want to consider building a hash of your lines instead:

```
open( my $input, '<', "text.txt" ) or die $!;
my %in_todd = map { $_ => 1 } <$input>;
close $input;
while (<>) {
   print if $in_todd{$_};
}
```

Note - you might want to watch for trailing linefeeds.